# Setting cellIdentifier in Nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Hi guys i have just quick question.
When I'm using tableview's method `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` is it necessary to set the same identifier in Nib file? Because in my opinion there is no need but i can't find any statement in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set identifier in Nib file. Just `registerNib` and use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.